# Error compiling a cuda project

Tags: c, cuda, nvcc

I'm having some trouble compiling a cuda project with C Cuda and the lodepng libraries.

My makefile looks like this.

```
gpu:    super-resolution.cu
    gcc -g -O -c lodepng.c
    nvcc -c super-resolution.cu
    nvcc -o super-resolution-cuda super-resolution.o 
    rm -rf super-resolution.o
    rm -rf lodepng.o
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, because it is complaining about

```
nvcc warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
super-resolution.o: In function `main':
parallel-algorithm/super-resolution.cu:238: undefined reference to `lodepng_decode32_file(unsigned char**, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, char const*)'
parallel-algorithm/super-resolution.cu:259: undefined reference to `lodepng_encode32_file(char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
parallel-algorithm/super-resolution.cu:269: undefined reference to `lodepng_encode32_file(char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
parallel-algorithm/super-resolution.cu:282: undefined reference to `lodepng_encode32_file(char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
parallel-algorithm/super-resolution.cu:292: undefined reference to `lodepng_encode32_file(char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
parallel-algorithm/super-resolution.cu:301: undefined reference to `lodepng_encode32_file(char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
...
```

I just need a way to compile my .cu file and add a C .o file into it during the compilation process using nvcc.

EDIT: tried suggestion. no success.

```
gcc -g -O -c lodepng.c
nvcc -c super-resolution.cu
nvcc warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
super-resolution.cu:1:2: warning: #import is a deprecated GCC extension [-Wdeprecated]
 #import "cuda.h"
  ^
super-resolution.cu(106): warning: expression has no effect

super-resolution.cu(116): warning: expression has no effect

super-resolution.cu(141): warning: variable "y" was declared but never referenced

super-resolution.cu:1:2: warning: #import is a deprecated GCC extension [-Wdeprecated]
 #import "cuda.h"
  ^
super-resolution.cu(106): warning: expression has no effect

super-resolution.cu(116): warning: expression has no effect

super-resolution.cu(141): warning: variable "y" was declared but never referenced

ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_00000851_00000000-5_super-resolution.ptx, line 197; warning : Double is not supported. Demoting to float
nvcc -o super-resolution-cuda super-resolution.o lodepng.o

nvcc warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
super-resolution.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_00000851_00000000-3_super-resolution.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `lodepng_decode32_file(unsigned char**, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, char const*)'
```

It still can't find the reference to the object file.
Edit: here's our .cu file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" unsigned lodepng_encode32_file(const char* ,const unsigned char* , unsigned , unsigned h);
extern "C" unsigned lodepng_decode32_file(unsigned char** , unsigned* , unsigned* ,const char* );
```

Comment: You're linking with `nvcc` but not including the object you built with gcc (`lodepng.o`).  try `nvcc -o super-resolution-cuda super-resolution.o lodepng.o` in place of your existing `nvcc -o super-resolution-cuda super-resolution.o` link step.

Comment: so the `lodepng_encode32_file` reference got sorted out but the `lodepng_decode32_file` reference did not?  Would probably need to see the exact code then to understand why and if you are doing C/C++ linking correctly (e.g. extern C, etc.)  Are you sure that both `lodepng_encode32_file` and `lodepng_decode32_file` are exported and used the same way?

Comment: Seriously?  You're posting these updates in the comments?  How about the corrsponding functions in lodepng?  Do their prototypes match?  I'm not sure this question can be answered with little snippets.  Create a complete, short, compilable case in the question that demonstrates the issue.  Yes, you will need to edit your files down substantially, it will require effort on your part.  But it should not be difficult, to edit 2 files down to the critical pieces that demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. don't `#import`.  If you want to include `cuda.h` (which should be unnecessary) then use `#include`.  Instead I would just delete that line from your `super-resolution.cu` file.
2. What you did not show before, but is now evident, is that in your `super-resolution.cu` you are including `lodepng.h` and *also* later specifying C-linkage for 2 functions: `lodepng_decode32_file` and `lodepng_encode32_file`.  When I tried compiling your `super-resolution.cu` the compiler gave me errors like this (I don't know why you don't see them):

   ```
   super-resolution.cu(8): error: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "lodepng_encode32_file"
   lodepng.h(184): here

   super-resolution.cu(9): error: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "lodepng_decode32_file"
   lodepng.h(134): here
   ```

   So basically you are tripping over C and C++ linkage.
3. I believe the simplest solution is to use `lodepng.cpp` (instead of `lodepng.c`), delete the following lines from your `super-resolution.cu`:

   ```
   extern "C" unsigned lodepng_encode32_file(const char* ,const unsigned char* , unsigned , unsigned h);
   extern "C" unsigned lodepng_decode32_file(unsigned char** , unsigned* , unsigned* ,const char* );
   ```

   And just compile everything and link everything c++ style:

   ```
   $ g++ -c lodepng.cpp
   $ nvcc -c super-resolution.cu
   nvcc warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
   $ nvcc -o super-resolution super-resolution.o lodepng.o
   nvcc warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
   $
   ```
4. If you really want to link `lodepng.o` c-style instead of c++ style, then you will need to modify `lodepng.h` with appropriate `extern "C"` wrappers where the necessary functions are called out.  In my opinion this gets messy.
5. If you want to get rid of the warnings about `sm_10` then add the `nvcc` switch to compile for a different architecture, e.g.:

   ```
   nvcc -arch=sm_20 ...
   ```

   but make sure whatever you choose is compatible with your GPU.

Comment: You don't need to change to `lodepng.cpp`, if the code was C then you should use a C compiler. Just have to straighten out the linkage specification.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple snippet of the code.

The lodepng library can be gotten from here (http://lodev.org/lodepng/).

Renaming it to C will make it usable on C.

Even at this level, there's compilation issues with

```
"undefined reference to `lodepng_decode32_file'"
"undefined reference to `lodepng_encode32_file'"
```

File: Makefile

```
all:    gpu
    gcc -g -O -c lodepng.c
    nvcc -c super-resolution.cu
    nvcc -o super-resolution-cuda super-resolution.o lodepng.o
    rm -rf super-resolution.o
    rm -rf lodepng.o
```

File: super-resolution.cu

```
#import "cuda.h"
#include "lodepng.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" unsigned lodepng_encode32_file(const char* ,const unsigned char* , unsigned , unsigned h);
extern "C" unsigned lodepng_decode32_file(unsigned char** , unsigned* , unsigned* ,const char* );

//GPU 3x3 Blur.
__global__ void gpuBlur(unsigned char* image, unsigned char* buffer, int width, int height)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x%width;
    int j = threadIdx.x/width;
    if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == width - 1 || j == height - 1)
        return;

    int k;
    for (k = 0; k <= 4; k++)
    {
        buffer[4*width*j + 4*i + k] =           (image[4*width*(j-1) + 4*(i-1) + k] +
                                image[4*width*(j-1) + 4*i + k] +
                                image[4*width*(j-1) + 4*(i+1) + k] +
                                image[4*width*j + 4*(i-1) + k] +
                                image[4*width*j + 4*i + k] +
                                image[4*width*j + 4*(i+1) + k] +
                                image[4*width*(j+1) + 4*(i-1) + k] +
                                image[4*width*(j+1) + 4*i + k] +
                                image[4*width*(j+1) + 4*(i+1) + k])/9;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Items for image processing;
    //int threshold = 100;
    unsigned int error;
    unsigned char* image;
    unsigned int width, height;

    //Load the image;
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        error = lodepng_decode32_file(&image, &width, &height, argv[1]);
        printf("Loaded file: %s[%d]\n", argv[1], error);
    }
    else
    {

        return 0;
    }

    unsigned char* buffer =(unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4*width*height);

    //GPU Blur Section.
    unsigned char* image_gpu;
    unsigned char* blur_gpu;
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &image_gpu, sizeof(char) * 4*width*height);
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &blur_gpu, sizeof(char) * 4*width*height);
    cudaMemcpy(image_gpu,image, sizeof(char) * 4*width*height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(blur_gpu,image, sizeof(char) * 4*width*height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    gpuBlur<<< 1, height*width >>> (image_gpu, blur_gpu, width, height);
    cudaMemcpy(buffer, blur_gpu, sizeof(char) * 4*width*height, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    //Spit out buffer as an image.
    error = lodepng_encode32_file("GPU_OUTPUT1_Blur.png", buffer, width, height);
    cudaFree(image_gpu);
    cudaFree(blur_gpu);

    free(buffer);
    free(image);

}
```

Comment: It's better to edit this type of material into your question.  Don't post an answer on SO unless you are really *answering* the question (even if it is your own question).